# Appengine Endpoints not generating all methods for client lib

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have several endpoints that I have been using. After updating to latest client libs and appengine version I have a problem with one of my endpoints where not all of the methods are being generated.  Only the standard REST methods are created in the client lib(and discovery docs).  My custom methods are not included.  All the methods are annotated per the directions and similar to my other endpoints.  Also this endpoint work with the previous version of appengine.  Anyone experienced this?  Will try to get some code up here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to my method being static.  Once I remove the static declaration everything worked fine.  In previous version the methods could be static.